Comments asigned correctly to answer objects but display in one answer objects
I'm building a question-and-answer platform to help companies understand their customers' needs. As you can see in the view_question views, I'm displaying an answer based on the question, and it is working perfectly. However, when displaying comments on the answer using this method:
answers = Answer.objects.filter(post=question)
answers_comment = CommentA.objects.filter(post=answers)

This method return an error in the template saying: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing. then i try to display it using this method:
answers = Answer.objects.filter(post=question)
answers_comment = CommentA.objects.filter(post__id__in=answers)

It seems like the problem is solved, but it is not. The answers_comment display all comment objects to a single answer object, even though they were not assigned to that answer.
{% for answer in answers %}
        <div class="row border-bottom">
            <div class="col col-answer">
                <div class="answer-icons">
                    <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="">
                        <span><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i></span>
                        <span>{{ answer.up_vote }}</span>
                    </a>
    
                    <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="">
                        <span><i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></span>
                        <span>{{ answer.down_vote }}</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="answer-text">
                    <p>{{answer.your_answer|convert_markdown|safe}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}



        <div class="comment-container m-2">
            {% for answer_comment in answers_comment %}
            <div class="row">
                <small>{{ answer_comment.comment }}</small>
                {% with answer_comment.user.account as account %}
                <a style="text-decoration: none;" class="user-avatar" href="{% url 'Public-Profile' slug=account.slug %}">
                    <span>{{ answer_comment.user.username }}
                    </span>
                </a>
                <small>{{ answer_comment.created_at|naturaltime }}</small>
                <hr>
                {% endwith %}
            </div>
            {% endfor %}

def view_question(request, slug):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, slug=slug)
    answers = Answer.objects.filter(post=question)
    answers_comment = CommentA.objects.filter(post__id__in=answers)
    context = {"question":question, "answers":answers, "answers_comment":answers_comment}
    return render(request, 'view_question.html', context)

models:
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    body = models.TextField()

class Answer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    your_answer = models.TextField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class CommentA(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


Please share you r models

@MohamedElKalioby Check the question again.

Try the following in your view
 answers_id = [a.id for a in answers]
 answers_comment = CommentA.objects.filter(post_id__in=answers)

This wont do a join as the post_id in already in the CommentA model.
Note: the issue here that you are sending all comments without knowing which answer they belong to which will make the template code much harder.
The solution is to use the reverse relationship lookup provide by django as follows
for answer in answers:
    for comment in answer.commentA_set.all():
         .....


The issue I'm encountering arises from how I'm retrieving comments for each answer. Since an answer can have multiple comments, I should iterate through each answer separately and retrieve its corresponding comments. Here's how I did it:
{% for answer in answers %}
    <div class="row border-bottom">
        <div class="col col-answer">
            <div class="answer-icons">
                <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="">
                    <span><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i></span>
                    <span>{{ answer.up_vote }}</span>
                </a>
                <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="">
                    <span><i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></span>
                    <span>{{ answer.down_vote }}</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-text">
                <p>{{ answer.your_answer|convert_markdown|safe }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Retrieve comments for this answer -->
    {% for comment in answer.comments.all %}
        <div class="comment-container m-2">
            <div class="row">
                <small>{{ comment.comment }}</small>
                <a style="text-decoration: none;" class="user-avatar" href="{% url 'Public-Profile' slug=comment.user.account.slug %}">
                    <span>{{ comment.user.username }}</span>
                </a>
                <small>{{ comment.created_at|naturaltime }}</small>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

In my CommentA models, I have to define a related_name for the ForeignKey from CommentA to simplify the reverse lookup.
class CommentA(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

